# addMouseListener to a program

Tags: java, html, swing, mouseevent, mouselistener

im trying to overwrite `mouseClicked` function of `MouseAdapter` then i can use it in my program as follow:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.lobobrowser.html.HtmlRendererContext;
import org.lobobrowser.html.UserAgentContext;
import org.lobobrowser.html.domimpl.HTMLLinkElementImpl;
import org.lobobrowser.html.gui.HtmlPanel;
import org.lobobrowser.html.parser.DocumentBuilderImpl;
import org.lobobrowser.html.parser.InputSourceImpl;
import org.lobobrowser.html.test.SimpleHtmlRendererContext;
import org.lobobrowser.html.test.SimpleUserAgentContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.html2.HTMLLinkElement;
import org.w3c.dom.html2.HTMLElement;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public  class test {



public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, 
            IOException, ParserConfigurationException {

        String uri = "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html";
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
        InputSource is = new InputSourceImpl(reader, uri);
        UserAgentContext uAgent = new SimpleUserAgentContext();
        final HtmlPanel htmlPanel = new HtmlPanel();
        final HtmlRendererContext rendererContext = (HtmlRendererContext) 
                new LocalHtmlRendererContext(htmlPanel, uAgent);
        DocumentBuilderImpl builder = new DocumentBuilderImpl(uAgent, rendererContext);
        Document document = builder.parse(is);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(htmlPanel);


        htmlPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("adr is equal to" + rendererContext.getCurrentURL());

                System.out.println("Clicked!" + e);
            }
        });

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        htmlPanel.setDocument(document, rendererContext);
        frame.setSize(400, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class LocalHtmlRendererContext extends SimpleHtmlRendererContext {

        public LocalHtmlRendererContext(HtmlPanel contextComponent, UserAgentContext uAgent) {
            super(contextComponent);
        }
    }
}
```

but it is not working. if i clik on any part of the form, nothing happens.

i tried     `htmlPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()` and     `frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()` both but no help.

EDIT:

i tried your suggestion, and i choosed BrowsertPanel instead of HtmlPanel, then i tried to get its component as follow:

```
org.lobobrowser.gui.AddressBarPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.BoxLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
org.lobobrowser.gui.SharedToolBarPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.BoxLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
org.lobobrowser.gui.FillerComponent[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=org.lobobrowser.util.gui.WrapperLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=32767,height=32767],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=0,height=0],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=32767,height=32767]]
org.lobobrowser.gui.StatusBarPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.BoxLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.BevelBorder@c2a132,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
```

also i added a navigationListener and when it navigates, i get the event as follow:

```
org.lobobrowser.ua.NavigationEvent[source=FramePanel[windowId=BrowserPanel.10481519,hashCode=23491286,parent=org.lobobrowser.gui.FillerComponent[,0,25,584x316,layout=org.lobobrowser.util.gui.WrapperLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=32767,height=32767],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=0,height=0],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=32767,height=32767]]]]
```

but i feel im lost in these components, it seems the `FillerComponent` or `FramePanel` are responsible for rendering, even so, i have no idea how to add listener to  them.

also found this [Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xamj/forums/forum/467020/topic/2119642) that someone described the steps to solve the problem, but seems so complicated to me? is there any pseudocode to distribute?

Comment: What exactly is an `HtmlPanel`?  Never mind.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  An SSCCE will answer that, as well as my next 10 questions.

Comment: @AndrewThompson if you mean a code runnable by copy/paste , i did but you need to get the lobobrowser library, how to add it?

Comment: I(1) am not prepared to download anything to test source code.  If the problem cannot be reproduced using core J2SE, it is likely a problem with the 3rd party API. A problem which you should take up with the supplier of that API.  Having said that, if you swap the `HtmlPane` for a `JEditotPane` & see the exact same 'null' behavior - that might then be an SSCCE.  1) ..and possibly a few people besides me, though I can only speak for myself.

Comment: @AndrewThompson so do you think the code generally right?

Comment: Probably not.  After all, it is not detecting mouse clicks, is it?  Besides that, it does two less than optimal things, neither of shich seems to be the immediate problem.  1) `setSize` on the frame rather than `setPreferredSize`/good layout for the content and `pack` on the frame. 2) The GUI should be started (& updated) on the EDT.

Answer (score 4):

This code (is an SSCCE &) works.  Try changing it one line at a time until you see the error manifest.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;

public  class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String uri = "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html";
        final URL url = new URL(uri);
        JEditorPane htmlPanel = new JEditorPane(url);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(htmlPanel);

        htmlPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("adr is equal to" + url);

                System.out.println("Clicked!" + e);
            }
        });

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

### Update

> ..seems bug is from htmlpanel

I did a bit of digging, based on the comment of StanislavL.  It seems a [`SimpleBrowserFrame`](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra-api/org/lobobrowser/html/test/SimpleBrowserFrame.html) extends `HtmlPanel` & provides the method [`getComponent()`](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra-api/org/lobobrowser/html/test/SimpleBrowserFrame.html#getComponent%28%29) which..

> Gets the component that renders the frame. ..

Perhaps if a `SimpleBrowser` was used, you could add the listener to the child and it would work.  Admittedly I am just guessing after a quick trawl though the docs.

Comment: ooh, seems bug is from htmlpanel

Comment: @AndrewThompson how about if you see my edit and see if there is anything to point ?

Comment: No idea further ideas, sorry.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i just wanna know how to access a component's child component and adding a listener to it, thats all, just generally for any component :)

Comment: `simpleBrowserFrame.getComponent().addMouseListener(...`  As an aside.  A developer capable of working with a poorly supported API should be highly experienced.  The nature of your questions suggest to me that you are not.  My recommendation is that you abandon this API, and if you cannot find a suitable replacement component, put the app. on hold.

Comment: i mean for the component[] type not component, the array one,cause it seems i need to add listener to the child of its child.. i would like to abandon but i have no other choice, no other pure java web engine

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess. Check children components of the htmlPanel. May be they cover whole panel. Try to attach the listener to all subcomponents after the HtmlPanel is filled with content.

Comment: @StanislavL `Check children components of the htmlPanel`, `by ignoring lobobrowser` just my curiosity, did you meaning Swing JComponet or Html component

Comment: hmm, how about more hint? you know , im new to java and shifted from C++ since 4 months ago, so it seems not familiar to me the way you explained things.

Comment: public Component[] getComponents() method of the panel. Check the children and check children of children.

Comment: i typed  **System.out.println(htmlPanel.getComponents().toString());**
and it returned **[Ljava.awt.Component;@337838**  what does [L] means?

Comment: htmlPanel.getComponents() is an array. Iterate through the items.

Comment: @StanislavL how about if you see my edit and see if there is anything to point ?

Comment: @StanislavL because for the component[] there is no further function to get the component of each item, so i wonder how it would be solved :)